# Does Stripe record a payee's IP address?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Stripe payment issue on a Client's Wordpress website running the Event Espresso plugin. For some reason, a payment successfully went through on Stripe but it appears the payment notification didn't make it back to my client's website. We've tested and can't replicate the issue. Our hosting provider have asked if we can provide the IP address of the successful payment, but I can't see any mention of a recorded IP address in the Stripe logs. Does anyone know if a record of a payee's IP address accessible anywhere?

Any help would be **hugely** appreciated!

Dave.

Comment: [You can always contact Stripe themselves.](https://support.stripe.com/email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it.  Doing their sample `curl` test from their api:

```
{
  "id": "ch_103qsK2eZvKYlo2CxP4IaIl9",
  "object": "charge",
  "created": 1397483829,
  "livemode": false,
  "paid": true,
  "amount": 400,
  "currency": "usd",
  "refunded": false,
  "card": {
    "id": "card_103qsK2eZvKYlo2CqxXRJvwq",
    "object": "card",
    "last4": "4242",
    "type": "Visa",
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2014,
    "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
    "customer": null,
    "country": "US",
    "name": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_zip_check": null
  },
  "captured": true,
  "refunds": [],
  "balance_transaction": "txn_103qsK2eZvKYlo2Cxe0IYgyp",
  "failure_message": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "customer": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "description": "Charge for test@example.com",
  "dispute": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "statement_description": null
}
```

The IP doesn't seem to be logged.   Since you are using PHP, you could always fetch the IP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Thanks Sircapsalot! I didn't think so either.

Comment: They probably do store it, since they use IP addresses in fraud scoring, but they don't expose it.